# Partitions overlapping linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems

I have problem with my partitions which are overlapping each other (`fdisk -l`)

```
/dev/sda1    *             2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2               8155136 220203007 212047872 101,1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3             220203008 639633407 419430400   200G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4                208894 976768064 976559171 465,7G  f extended W95 (LBA)
/dev/sda5                208896   8155135   7946240   3,8G 82 exchange partition
/dev/sda6             639645696 976768064 337122369 160,8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

How can I repair that ? Is deleting all the hard drive could repair this ?

Comment: are you seeing specific problems?  they're not overlapping -- sda(5,2,3,6) are contained within sda4 (in that order).  examine start/end sectors and compare sizes to verify.  the only odd thing is that sda(2,3) are normally **primary** partitions, and yours should be **logical** partitions.  could be a corrupted MBR, could be a buggy partitioning tool.  if it works, ignore it.

Comment: i should specify -- if all these partitions work, and you **never need to change these partitions**, you should be fine.  but i don't know that fdisk or other tools won't imagine 300G of free space in the extended partition and let you create additional partitions there, which **would** overlap with sda(2,3).

Comment: So why Gparted then showing me overlapping partitions and there is 300 GO space where it is not allocated.

Comment: i suspect you've got a nonstandard partition table (sda2 & sda3 should be logical partitions, but that would show as sda7 & sda8) and it is confusing `gparted`.  if you have any data that you care about, **back it up now** before you make any further changes with `gparted` or other tools.  (the easiest proper fix will be to wipe the drive and start over with a fresh partition table.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with quixotic's comment:

> If all these partitions work, and you **never need to change these partitions**, you should be fine.

This partition table is very unusual. It looks like mangled MBR-based partitioning scheme. I will help you understand what's going on.

---

To know the partitions a program (like `fdisk` or `gparted`) performs the following analysis:

1. *Master Boot Record* (MBR) at sector `0` is read. It contains four partition entries, they are given numbers `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`. Any entry that's not empty defines a partition with corresponding number (like `sda1` for the 1st entry). Notice you can have any set of these entries non-empty, so it's possible to have e.g. `sda2` and `sda4` only.

These partitions shouldn't overlap. It's a good practice to have them in order (first table entry goes first on the disk and so on). There's no need to leave any "unused" sectors between these partitions nor at the end; still it's common to have few "unused" sectors between MBR and the first partition. By "unused" I mean "not belonging to any partition", still they can be used for something else – e.g. sectors between MBR and the first partition are commonly used to store a stage of bootloader (that's why your `sda1` starts at `2048`, not at `1`).

In your case there are `sda1`, `sda2`, `sda3` and `sda4` defined in MBR. Their entries are not exactly in disk order but it really doesn't matter (still it may confuse users). What matters is: `sda2` and `sda3` are within `sda4`, so formally the partitions **do overlap**. Programs like `gparted` detect this and raise a warning. In a moment I will explain why it's not fatal in your particular case.

2. At most one of these partitions can be an *extended partition* (others are called *primary partitions*). If there is one, then further analysis will be performed.

Your `sda4` is an *extended partition*.

3. An *extended partition* is not supposed to hold a filesystem. Instead, it may contain zero or more *logical partitions*. The very first sector of the *extended partition* is called *extended boot record* (EBR) and describes the first *logical partition* (if any). The number associated with this partition is always `5` and it must begin after its EBR. The first EBR may point to the second EBR which describes partition number `6` (which must begin after its EBR); the second EBR may point to the third one and so on. Eventually some EBR doesn't point to the next and it means it describes the last partition. EBRs don't store their numbers, they are like links of a chain. For this reason *logical partitions* have consecutive numbers.

In your case the sector number `208894` contains EBR that describes `sda5`. There is also another EBR, probably somewhere between `639633408` and `639645695` that describes `sda6`. The only two *logical partitions* don't fill the whole `sda4`, that's why `gparted` tells you there is 300 GB of free space. If you examine the contents of `sda4` only, you see free space. If you examine entries in MBR only, you see overlapping partitions. The trick is `sda2` and `sda3` fit into this allegedly free space – **that's why the overlapping isn't fatal.**

`gparted` is not smart enough to spot this because your setup is so unusual, crazy I would say.

Another comment:

> I don't know that `fdisk` or other tools won't imagine 300G of free space in the extended partition and let you create additional partitions there, which would overlap with `sda(2,3)`.

I say It's highly possible they let you break things this way.

---

So what can you do? If it works, don't touch.

Well, one could deal with this mess and make the partition layout perfectly sane, but (e.g.):

- some partition numbers would change, I expect problems booting Windows (there is Windows, isn't there?);
- *primary* `sda2` should be new *logical* `sda6` but there is no free sector between them for EBR.

With careful (and manual) partition table editing, partition moving/resizing, repairing the boot process etc. this can be done. Many things can go wrong though.

---

> Can deleting all the hard drive repair this?

You mean: backup important files, delete all the partitions, create sane partitions and filesystems from scratch, install OSes, then copy the files back? Yes, it would repair this.