# How does Linux number disk partitions?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, numbering

As I know on a MBR disk primary partitions are numbered 1 to 4 and numbers from 5 onwards are for logical partitions. So the partition at the first position on sda will be sda1, the next one sda2, etc. And that's true for drives I previously worked with

However recently I've had chances to repartition some PCs and while tinkering with those systems and I noticed that their volume numbers are **not in order**. For example sda3 lies before sda1 in the below screenshot

[image: gparted1]

The numbering is **consistent across reboots** and they're the same even in other live distros I tried.

So how are those numbers determined when there's no file for storing the number settings?

Some other examples:

[image: gparted2]

[image: gparted3]

Comment: About logical partitions: The very first sector of the extended partition is called extended boot record (EBR) and describes the first logical partition (if any). The number associated with this partition is always 5 and it must begin after its EBR. The first EBR may point to the second EBR which describes partition number 6 (which must begin after its EBR); the second EBR may point to the third one and so on. Note that "after its EBR" may be "way after", plus EBRs may not be in order; so `sda5` can be after `sda6` etc. See [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1185297/432690).

Comment: I see the same on GPT.

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE GPT also has a list of partition tables like MBR, just bigger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when there's no file for storing the number settings?

There is the MBR itself.

Partitions are not numbered according to what space they occupy, but according to which slot they use in the on-disk "partition table" (the MBR or GPT). The first slot of the MBR partition table gets `sda1` (no matter which disk area it describes), the second slot gets `sda2`, and so on.

There are various reasons why you can end up with an unsorted partition table. (You can use the command-line `fdisk` tool to sort it.) Most partitioning tools try to keep these slots "in order" automatically, so that the "leftmost" partition is always sda1, etc. But some other tools don't, because not all operating systems can cope with their boot partition's slot changing.

Comment: "The first slot of the MBR partition table gets sda1 (no matter which disk area it describes), the second slot gets sda2, and so on" So, if only slot 4 is populated in the MBR, do you only get `sda4` and no `sda1`, `2` or `3`?